# Custom hook that is called in two components, a father and a child, doesn't update in the father

Tags: reactjs, react-custom-hooks

folks!

I created a custom hook that is called two times, in a father component and also in a child component, the problem is that when the state of the hook changes the child is rendered, but the father component is not updated.

I'm breaking any custom hooks rule?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my bad...

Two calls to a custom hook, two states.